# How to share common flow in two React projects serving different clients?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, frontend, micro-frontend

There are two React frontend repos that serve two different clients. Both of them have the similar UI components and pages but they differ in logic at some places and have different APIs integrated. So response from API might differ for the same component and minor tweaks are made for the component but still they remain almost same in structre and styling. Any solution for this?